# Como o PDOStatement::fetchObject funciona

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou tentando setar os valores retornados de uma consulta para um objeto de outra classe da seguinte forma:

```
public function select($id,Cliente $cliente) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM compras WHERE id = :id AND email = :email";
    $stm = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
    //SETANDO PARAMETROS DA QUERY
    $stm->bindValue(':id',$id);
    $stm->bindValue(':email',$cliente->getEmail());
    //EXECUTANDO QUERY
    $stm->execute();
    //OBTENDO RESULTADO
    if($resultado = $stm->fetchObject('Compra')) {
      return $resultado;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }//select
```

Como devo montar o método mágico `__construct` do objeto Compra?

Comment: +1 porque a pergunta é muito boa. Eu também tinha muito essa dúvida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse caso, você não precisa definir um construtor. Quando você usa `PDOStatement::fetchObject` para determinar qual objeto será usado para representar os dados vindos de uma consulta, o `PDO` definirá os valores às propriedades diretamente, da mensa maneira que se faz um simples `array`.

Para você entender isso, você primeiro precisa entender que, no PHP, para você definir um valor de uma propriedade de uma classe, você não precisa declará-la na classe. Você pode simplesmente atribuir diretamente, é claro, desde que a mesma não tenha sido declarada na classe como `protected` ou `private`.

Veja:

```
Obj {
      public $nome;
}

$obj = new Obj;

$obj->nome = "Wallace"; // declarado
$obj->idade = 26; // Não declarado


var_dump($obj);
```

O resultado é :

```
object(Obj)#168 (2) {
  ["nome"]=>
  string(7) "Wallace"
  ["idade"]=>
  int(26)
}
```

## Usando métodos mágicos

Quando você perguntou sobre a definição no construtor, ficou completamente compreensível que você deseja adicionar um comportamento à sua classe para definir como os valores serão definidos.

Como foi dito, com o construtor isso não é possível, pois o `PDOStatement::fetchObject` não usa o construtor, mas ele atribuirá os valores um por um (externamente, por assim dizer).

A solução para driblar esse problema é usando o método mágico chamado `__set`. Com ele você determina um comportamento para sua classe quando uma propriedade não for declarada ou acessível no seu objeto.

Exemplo:

```
public function Obj {
      protected $items;

      public function __set($key, $value) {
            $this->items[$key] = $value;
      }
}
```

Sendo assim, os resultados seriam diferentes.

Veja:

```
$obj = new Obj;
$obj->nome = "Wallace";
$obj->idade = 26;

object(Obj)#165 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(7) "Wallace"
    ["idade"]=>
    int(26)
  }
}
```

## Usando o construtor

Se você quiser usar o construtor, você terá que passar os resultados desejado manualmente para o construtor.

```
 $array = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 new Obj($array);
```

Comment: ok, nesse caso então eu teria de fazer um $resultado = $pdo->fetchObject(); e depois manipular esse objeto jogando o mesmo como parametro no construct da classe que quero que esses valores sejam setados?

Comment: Só um minuto, ainda estou editando a resposta, vou colocar todas as informações que você precisa :p

Comment: @RenoirDosReis pronto, creio que a edição tirará todas suas dúvidas.

Comment: muito bom cara, obrigado.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters O método `__set` não é chamado pelo PDO quando os campos são definidos? Tentei fazer algo parecido com isso aqui e mesmo com o campo privado ele ignorou o `__set`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss *Como foi dito, com o construtor isso não é possível, pois o PDOStatement::fetchObject não usa o construtor, mas ele atribuirá os valores um por um (externamente, por assim dizer).*